# Unable to find the controller for path "/api/login_check". The route is wrongly configured

Tags: symfony, security

I have a problem with "login_check" and i use Symfony 3 and LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle.

The problem :

[image: The route is wrongly configured.]

The security.yml :

```
firewalls:

    login:
        pattern:   ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        form_login:
            username_parameter: username
            password_parameter: password
            check_path:               /api/login_check
            success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            require_previous_session: false
    api:
        pattern: ^/api
        stateless: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

    main:
        anonymous: true

access_control:
   - {path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
   - {path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

The routing.yml :

```
app:
resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
type: rest
prefix: /api
```

login_check:
    path: api/login_check

Can you help me, please?

good day :)

Comment: I'm in localhost and the access_control has been moved correctly.

Comment: Could you put code samples as code, not as an images? Because people may want to copy code, try to reproduce your issue. I really don't want to type your security.yml file from scratch. But it's the only thing I can do in order to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Here, thank you for the advice.

Comment: Did you use a POST request? (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888961/symfony2-unable-to-find-the-controller-for-path-api-login-check-the-route))

Answer (score 0):

Change your routing file with:

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: rest
    prefix: /api

api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check
```